# Fragment - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException Android

Tags: java, android

**UPDATE** : The common error that leads to NullPointerException is by using `getActivity()` in Fragment instead of the Inflated `View v`.

**Problem :**

```
public class Products extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_produits, container , false);

    listProduitsList=(ListView ) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_produitsList);//<- Mistake here

    /**
    * SOME CODE HERE
    */
    return v;
}
```

**Edit :** access to layout ressource in fragment via the inflated view.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_produits, container , false);
```

**Cause :**

```
listProduitsList=(ListView ) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_produitsList);
```

getActivity() contain the Main Activity Resources not the Fragment , this will cause a NullPointerException.

**FIX** :

```
listProduitsList=(ListView ) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_produitsList);
```

**LOGCAT :**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.x/com.example.x.Catalogue}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Please post LogCat output. Otherwise your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where is the logcat?

Comment: Initialize ListView using v not getActivity() : v.findViewById(R.id.lv_produitsList)

Comment: Logcat done  , UPDATED

Comment: use `v.findViewById()` in Fragments

Comment: what is there at Products.onCreateView(Products.java:51) ?

Comment: Thanks you  EpicPandaForce u are right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to find `ListView` which is define in `Fragment` layout, `onCreateView` method you inflate fragment layout into `v (View)` so you find `ListView` using `v (View)` as below :

```
v.findViewById(R.id.lv_produitsList)
```

Instead of

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_produitsList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `View` to use `findViewById`

So change it :

```
listProduitsList=(ListView ) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_produitsList);
```

To :

```
listProduitsList=(ListView ) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_produitsList);
```